# What is a RSBOperation, in the context of CData's JDBC library for access to QuickBooks.=

Tags: sql, jdbc, quickbooks, cdata, cdata-drivers

I am using the JDBC driver from CData(cdata.com) to access a QuickBooks instance. The code below is right off the CData website(with the exception of qbConnString). The getConnection call works fine, but an exception is thrown when the query is executed.

```
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(qbConnString);

            String cmd = "INSERT INTO Customers (LastName) VALUES (?)";
            QuickBooksPreparedStatement pstmt =   
              (QuickBooksPreparedStatement) connection.prepareStatement(cmd,
                Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
            pstmt.setString(1, "Hook");
            int count = pstmt.executeUpdate();
            System.out.println(count + " rows are affected");
            ResultSet rs = pstmt.getGeneratedKeys();
            while (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println(rs.getString("ListId"));
            }
            connection.close();
```

Here is the stack trace that is generated when executeUpdate is called:

```
XcoreXquickbooksX160X6254.ymc: The attribute name is required by RSBOperation.
    at XcoreXquickbooksX160X6254.qi.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
    at app.JDBCConnect.qbConnect(JDBCConnect.java:49)
    at app.JDBCConnect.<init>(JDBCConnect.java:34)
    at app.JDBCConnect.main(JDBCConnect.java:25)
```

So my question is: what is a RSBOperation and where can I find documentation concerning the missing requirement?

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the driver to me, report it to the vendor.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it was user error. I got mixed up; duh.

My code is targeting QuickBooks Desktop. I copied that code from a  QuickBook POS (point of sale) page, not the regular QuickBooks Desktop page.

The Customer table in the POS application, apparently, has a column named "name" not "LastName". The Customer table in the regular QuickBooks app DOES have a column named "LastName" and that was what I wanted to do.

Someone please correct me if I'm wrong, but, the message "The attribute name is required by RSBOperation" could be replaced with something like "The Customer table does not have a column named "LastName".

Comment: You are probably right, it might be worth reporting as an improvement request.